# Android: Send HTML text using ACTION_SEND Intent

Tags: android, html, css, android-intent, android-sharing

I'm trying to send some `HTML` formatted text via the `ACION_SEND` `Intent` in my app. The `HTML` file is located in my `assets` directory and it has links to some images and contains other `CSS` stylings. Thus far I've tried the following:

```
private Intent getEmailIntent(String deepLink) {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//      sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
//      sharingIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getShareSubject());
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  Html.fromHtml(getHtmlTextFromAssetsFile("myHtml.html")));
        return sharingIntent;
    }
```

As you can see from the above method, I've tried using all three of the `IntentTypes` in the code, without success.

The `HTML` file has `CSS` within a `<style>` tag , and that is not applied. It just shows up as plain text in all cases. No images (remotely located) are loaded. And `</br>` tags are ignored.

Has anyone worked with this? How can I get my app to send such an email? Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not many email clients on Android support HTML. What you can do is  providing plain text in `EXTRA_TEXT` and putting the HTML in `EXTRA_HTML_TEXT` as documented here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND